# How do defence lawyers get away with saying "he didn't do it" when they only can prove the uncertainty that he did?

Tags: criminal-law, common-law, lawyer, jury, professional-ethics

Following various criminal trials (like [this one](https://www.stuff.co.nz/national/crime/300366508/desert-road-murder-case-bao-chang-wang-killing-was-ordered-by-drug-ring-leader)) I often see defence lawyers claim that the defendant unequivocally *did not* commit the crime whereas they do not actually present (or claim to have) evidence to that effect (e.g. alibi): they only cast arguably reasonable *doubt that he did*.

That is, on the following diagram, the defence may have somewhat good chances to land *above* the orange line (e.g., as in the linked case, they simply say that the prosecution witness is a liar). Nevertheless they claim to be at the green top (like they have an alibi):

[image]

How are those clearly illogical claims allowed? Aren't lawyers expected to sound coherent? Why don't they instead say what they have i.e. "guilt needs to be proved beyond reasonable doubt but here *is* very reasonable doubt" — instead of blunt "he did not do it"? Is the latter just some sort of traditional courtroom rhetorical bullshit aimed to influence the jury, for some reason allowed by judges and not even pointed to by prosecutors — even though the jury *will* be instructed by the judge on the standard of proof required?

(Any common law jurisdiction)

Comment: Legally, "He didn't do it" and "You don't have proof beyond reasonable doubt that he did it" are the same.

Comment: @gnasher729 Source? I would say "not guilty" is legally "we're not sure if he did" rather than "he didn't do it".

Comment: There are only two possible states of guilt in almost all jurisdictions: yes or no. Logically, if it cannot be the first, it must be the second.

Comment: @Nij The "no" state of guilt simply means that he is _not proved_ to be guilty. It does not logically rule out that he in fact still _may_ be — it just allows him to legally walk away.

Comment: How do you get away with saying in a job interview "I'm 100% sure that I can handle this job." Wouldn't it be more logical and correct to say something like "Although I'm reasonably confident in my ability to perform this job, however, since I will be new to the job, I must foresee the possibility of circumstances from time to time which may make it difficult for me to perform at 100% efficiency; therefore I would caution that any performance estimates of my work cannot be guaranteed." Maybe that's the reality, but with that kind of sell, I wonder if you'd get the job.

Comment: @Brandin That's flawed analogy. Your two ways of saying in a job interview are close to each other in their meaning. Conversely, "doubtfully committed crime" and "did not commit crime" are far apart.

Comment: @Greendrake: Source - plenty of posts on law.stackexchange.com. Legally, you are either innocent or guilty, not something else. (Well, you might be dead and not count as innocent or guilty, or someone might have invented a figure as a scapegoat and that fictitious person is neither guilty nor innocent).

Comment: @ gnasher729 1  no, legally you are **found** guilty or found not guilty. It is perfectly possible for a person to be found guilty, convicted and sentenced who is in fact innocent. In US practice no one is ever found innocent, by the way, and "not guilty" simply means "not proved guilty beyond a reasonable doubt".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A defense lawyer may in fact believe that the accused is in fact innocent, even if the lawyer does not have solid proof of that fact.

But what a lawyer says during an opening argument need not be what the lawyer in fact thinks, nor what the lawyer can surely prove.  It will be what the lawyer wants the jury to conclude from the evidence to be presented. It will usually include mention of specific evidence that will be presented, and how the lawyer wants the jury to interpret and connect those items of evidence. It may also include predictions about  what evidence the other side will offer, and what weight or lack of weight the lawyer wants the jury to give such evidence.

The conclusions that the lawyer invites the jury to draw should be ones that could reasonably follow from the evidence that the lawyer expects to be presented. It is not proper for the lawyer to intentionally mislead the jury about what the evidence will show, but it is proper, indeed expected,  for the lawyer to but the best interpretation reasonably possible on the expected evidence. The lawyer's own beliefs are not at issue and are not normally mentioned.

There is no rule that requires the lawyer to limit the claims and conclusions made to what can be strictly proved by the evidence that the lawyer intends to present. They can be conclusions that reasonably but not necessarily follow from the expected evidence

There rules in a closing argument are somewhat more restrictive, but not very much. There a lawyer cannot refer to evidence that was never presented, or was ruled not admissible. But a lawyer may suggest whatever conclusions s/he thinks the jury can be reasonably persuaded to draw from that evidence, whether the lawyer personally believes those conclusions or not, and no matter whether such conclusions necessarily follow from the evidence.

It is unusual for a lawyer to argue "Perhaps the defendant did it, but the state can't prove that" even though in many cases that woulds be an objective summery of the defense case. Nothing requires the defense to argue in those terms.

Comment: "_There is no rule that requires the lawyer to limit the claims and conclusions made to what can be strictly proved by the evidence that the lawyer intends to present._" — but isn't it misleading/deceptive to to make unsupported claims? Doesn't the duty of fidelity to court get violated?

Comment: @Greendrake a conclusion that plausibly follows from evidence may not be strictly proved by that evidence. A jury may adopt any conclusion that reasonably follows from the evidence, and the lawyer may argue for any such conclusion. The lawyer's fist duty is to the client, although the lawyer may not claim that evidence will be presented knowing that it in fact will not be, nor may the lawyer argue for a conclusion that no reasonable person would reach from the evidence.

Answer (score 5):

In the case you link, this was given as an opening statement by the defense. Opening statements do not contain evidence. The defendant may or may not testify on their own behalf during the trial - this testimony, if given, counts as evidence, even if it is somewhat self-serving. And anything which tends to casts doubt as to the defendant's guilt is *evidence* that they didn't do it, even if it isn't *proof*.

If there is reasonable doubt, then "he didn't do it" is *not* illogical. And it would seem unfair to allow the prosecution to say "he did it" but *not* allow the defense to say "no he didn't".

Comment: Care to elaborate on 'If there is reasonable doubt, then "he didn't do it" is _not_ illogical'? Sure that casting some reasonable doubt is all that is needed for not guilty verdict, but I don't see how the instant transition from "doubtfully did" to "did not" could possibly be logical. The latter only makes sense when alibi is available, and only the former needs to be proved by the defence in any event.

Comment: @Greendrake you can assert in your opening argument that the defendant didn't do it even if you can't prove it but can only introduce reasonable doubt about the prosecution's case.  The defense is not required to prove statements of innocence; only the prosecution is required to prove its accusation of guilt. That follows from the presumption of innocence.

Comment: @Greendrake It's a rhetorical statement.  Keep in mind that most people on the jury aren't trained lawyers and may hear "We will show there is reasonable doubt the defendant did it" as "We'd be lying if we said the defendant didn't do it so we're couching our words."

Comment: @phoog Does that give the defense carte blanche for making unsupported claims?

Comment: @Greendrake By that I mean: If there is reasonable doubt, then by definition it is possible that the defendant did not, in fact, do it. It's not illogical to make an assertion which might be true.

Comment: _"It's not illogical to make an assertion which might be true."_ — sorry but in the context of fact trial it is only logical to make assertions of exactly what can be [subsequently] proved. If something only _might_ be true, it is not logical to assert that _is_ is true.

Comment: @Greendrake it's a trial, not a stack exchange answer.  The defense can make whatever claims it wants, supported or otherwise, in its opening arguments.  The defense generally has no burden of proof.  A trial is not an exercise in establishing the absolute truth; it's an exercise in evaluating whether the state can prove its case.

Comment: @phoog That would be a perfect answer if it explained how that gets away from the lawyer's [duty of fidelity to court](https://www.legislation.govt.nz/regulation/public/2008/0214/latest/DLM1437936.html) and is not [misleading or deceptive conduct](https://www.legislation.govt.nz/regulation/public/2008/0214/latest/LMS518143.html).

Comment: @Greendrake Your second link pretty much gives the reason: "conduct that is ... *likely to mislead or deceive*." So do you really think a jury member is likely to be *misled* by the fact that the defence phrased the opening statement with a blunt "he didn't do it" rather than phrasing it as a more wishy-washy "he most likely didn't do it" or some other variant of that? If you think about it it's pretty obvious why the defence shouldn't say it in that way -- it just makes it sound like you're not sure of what case you're making. Your job is to show he didn't do it and to show why.

Answer (score 4):

The link involves a New Zealand case, and I don't know what the ethical rules there say about this practice.

In Colorado, where I practice, which is also a common law jurisdiction, it is categorically prohibited, at a matter of attorney ethics, for an attorney in a trial to express a personal opinion as to whether or not a crime was committed or whether or not someone was truthful.

Instead, in opening argument, a lawyer must generally say something along the lines of "the evidence will show" and that based upon what the evidence will show, that the jury should rule a certain way. Certainty that the evidence will show what is said is not required, but the lawyer must have a good faith belief that the evidence is reasonably likely to show what is claimed (and as a tactical matter saying it will show something when it doesn't is a bad call).

In closing argument, the lawyer should summarize what the evidence was, what a reasonable person could infer from that evidence, and explain how that applies to the law set forth in the jury instructions, and then that based on that, that they jury should rule in a particular way.

An attorney should generally not put his or her own credibility at issue by implying personal knowledge of the facts in trial practice. When a prosecutor does that, it can be grounds for a mistrial ruling in addition to ethical sanctions.

Comment: Worth noting that the link is to what a journalist said the lawyer said, not necessarily what they actually said. True enough for journalism is a lower standard of truth than true enough for court.

Comment: Wow, so, in Colorado, wouldn't a defense lawyer be allowed to state that the defendant did not commit the crime unless they promise and intend to admit evidence to exactly that effect — as opposed to evidence that only casts reasonable doubt?

Comment: @Greendrake Even then, you really should say "The evidence which show . . .  from which the only reasonable inference is that Defendant did not commit the crime," although the courts might allow a certain amount of poetic license if it is clear that there is no implied reliance on personal knowledge of the attorney.

Answer (score 1):

In England and Wales, if a solicitor *knows* that a statement they are making is false or misleading (e.g. the client has admitted to them that he did something but wants the solicitor to tell the court that he didn't) then they are obliged to stop acting for their client. This is because of a conflict between the following rules in the [SRA code of conduct](https://www.sra.org.uk/solicitors/standards-regulations/code-conduct-solicitors/):

**1.4:** *"You do not mislead or attempt to mislead your clients, the court or others, either by your own acts or omissions or allowing or being complicit in the acts or omissions of others (including your client)."*

**3.1:** *"You only act for clients on instructions from the client, or from someone properly authorised to provide instructions on their behalf. If you have reason to suspect that the instructions do not represent your client's wishes, you do not act unless you have satisfied yourself that they do. However, in circumstances where you have legal authority to act notwithstanding that it is not possible to obtain or ascertain the instructions of your client, then you are subject to the overriding obligation to protect your client's best interests."*

**6.3:** *"You keep the affairs of current and former clients confidential unless disclosure is required or permitted by law or the client consents."*

For example, you know for a fact that your client did X. Your client instructs you to tell the court that he did Y instead. You therefore do not have his consent under rule 6.3 to disclose to the court the fact that he did X. You cannot tell the court that he did Y because that would be a breach of rule 1.4. Yet if you act at all, you are under an obligation to tell the court that he did Y under rule 3.1.

Whatever you do, you will breach at least one rule. The only way to avoid this is to stop acting for the client. When informing the court of this you will need to be careful not to state the reason why you are stepping back from the case in order not to breach rule 6.3. The courts should not insist on an explanation in such cases.

I assume a similar rule exists for barristers but I am not personally familiar with their code of conduct or with the rules in other jurisdictions.